# Как добавить кнопку в FlowDocument?

Tags: wpf, xaml

Мне нужно добавить кнопку в FlowDocument для того чтобы возвращаться на предыдущее меню. Обычным способом "перетащить кнопку" не выходит сделать. Погуглив я не нашел решения проблемы. Что мне прописать в XAML для того чтобы добавить эту кнопку? Прошу помочь здесь в решение проблемы. Пишу в VS2010

Answer (score 2):

Попробуйте так:

```
<FlowDocumentScrollViewer VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto">
    <FlowDocument>
        <Paragraph>
          <Button Click="someButton_Click" Content="Нажми меня!" />
        </Paragraph>
    </FlowDocument>
</FlowDocumentScrollViewer>
```